# Argument of type 'int' is incompatible with parameter of type 'char'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple tic tac toe game using c++ as part of some homework but having difficulty drawing the board. I'm trying to draw a basic board using hyphens (dashes) like:

```
- - -
- - -
- - -
```

But I get the error "Argument of type 'int' is incompatible with parameter of type 'char'". Can someone please help by pointing me in the right direction?

My code is as follows:

```
char empty = '-';

int size = 9;
int width = 3;

void showBoard(char board[]);

void showBoard(char board[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            board[i] = empty;

          cout << board << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    showBoard(10);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `10` to do?

Comment: Sorry, it's was supposed to be 9 and I was expecting it to display 9 hyphens.

Comment: @cvandal, the compiler sees it almost as if you'd written a statement like `char board[] = 10;` -- `10` just can't be legally interpreted as an array of characters, because it's just an integer.

Comment: Why do you have a `for` loop with `j` without ever using `j`?

Comment: It was in preparation to use a multidimensional array if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted `char tiles[] = "---------"; showBoard(tiles);` instead of `showBoard(10)`.

Also,

```
board[i] = empty;
```

is misplaced for `showBoard()`.  It should be somewhere else (create another function, e.g.).  Otherwise `showBoard()` becomes overloaded and confusing to those who would read the code.  Better still, consider a `Board` class with a `show()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is expecting `char[]`, but you're passing `int`. Those types are obviously incompatible.

This should be compatible though:

```
char board[] = "123456789";
showBoard(board);
```

Comment: That shouldn't work in C++11, and it should give warnings prior to that because of storing a string literal in a `char *`.

Comment: @chris Had to compile it to believe it :) you're right, updated.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider splitting your showBoard function into 2 routines: initializeBoard and showBoard.

Your initializeBoard routine should look like this:

```
void initializeBoard(char board[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         board[i] = empty;
    }
 }
```

The showBoard routine is:

```
void showBoard(char board[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size/width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

         cout << board[i*width +j] << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Finally you set up the top like this:

```
char board[9];

initializeBoard(board);
showBoard(board);
```